Internal Json RPC error with Ethers, MetaMask, BSC randomly when transfer USDT
I am currently trying to deposit my USDT from wallet A to wallet B on my Dapp. While making the transaction, I will prompt the metamask in order for user to approve or reject the transaction.
After prompting the metamask and the user approve the transaction, my code will trigger the function of sendTransaction.
However, sometime I get the error message of Internal Json RPC error, it shows failed on my metamask, but my transaction is successful in bscscan and the USDT is transferred from wallet A to wallet B successfully.
The nonce Id is 349 and the RPC I am using is a subscribed ankr premium RPC. This error does not happen on every transaction, it happens randomly. Probably once every 10+ or 20 attempts of transaction.
Here are some of the attachments for your reference.
and this is my transaction log at bscscan: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x4495c8fbf819bc775748c6282666c1eed24e227d16989c5bc280c93b2a8b44df
Here is my code:
let nonce = 0;

            try {
                nonce = await tmpProvider.getTransactionCount(await signer.getAddress());
                console.log('Nonce:', nonce);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching nonce:', error);
            }

            const burnTx = await signer.populateTransaction({
                to: usdtContractAddress,
                value: 0,
                data: usdtContract.interface.encodeFunctionData("transfer", [recipientAddress, amount]),
                nonce: nonce
            })

            const estimatedGas = await signer.estimateGas(burnTx);
            const gasLimit = estimatedGas + 1000000n;
            burnTx.gasLimit = gasLimit;
            
            const tx = await signer.sendTransaction(burnTx);

Thank you.
Attachment (Images):
This is the transaction in my metamask which is failed
This is the transaction that shows success on bscscan
This is the error I get

It smells like RPC provider issue. Can you try to switch to some other provider and see if the issue repeats, e.g. dRPC.

@MikkoOhtamaa Hi, may I know which RPC provider is more stable and recommended? My current provider sometime returns me error of Already_Exists: already known error as well during transaction but the transaction is successfully made at bscscan.

Quicknode has been the most reliable one for me. However the all SaaS RPC provides are crap. You usually want to send your tx through multiple providers and have fallbacks when reading data back.

@MikkoOhtamaa So, it is normal that rpc will return us some errors but transaction still manages to made successfully at bscscan? If that's the case, how should I handle the situation, other than switching to other provider? I have an issue when user makes withdrawal, frontend will show the error message from the rpc provider but the transaction is actually successful. Therefore, the amount of the user's wallet dAPP doesn't deduct as the function will only trigger when the rpc response message return is successful.

In Ethereum, you need to deal issues with this. The infrastructure is low quality. You can try to switch RPC providers and then spam Alchemy support if you can confirm it is their bug.

The only way to be sure is that you run your own RPC node, you know exactly what it is doing and you are not at the mercy of the third party APIs. This is the benefit of public blockchains.
